# Access json thougth interface in Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have this interface

```
interface User{
    name: String,
}
```

Then this method:

```
printValue(path: WhatGoesHere?<User>){ // some type for helping autocomplete
    const JSON = {
        name: "Andres",
    }
    console.log(JSON[path]);
}
```

What i want is to have "intellisense" for sending the path param, so i want to do something like

```
printValue(User.name); // here intelisense shows and helps to write User.name
```

and get as result "Andres"

Is this possible? thanks in advance

Comment: There's no JSON involved in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface User {
  name: String;
}

function printValue(path: keyof User) {
  const JSON = {
    name: "Andres",
  };
  console.log(JSON[path]);
}

printValue('name')
```

In this way you can access

Comment: Yes, thats wat i was searching for, thanks, is something like this available for nested properties?